# Issues with Lenovo C440

Tags: 12.04, uefi

New Lenovo C440, initialised m/s to check machine and validate warranty. otherwise nought on it, apart from usual buy this, use this garbage that came pre-installed.

Burned new disc (12.04.2 64AMD) from Ubuntu site and it ran checksum to validate, happy loaded  disc into new machine, wouldn't boot from BIOS like my old Lenovo N200 laptop. But it would open an wubi.exe file in m/s and install, running checks, with "success message", to reboot.

1. Upon rebooting it showed dual icons to choose either Ubuntu or M/S. Lol dual boot..?
2. Start Ubuntu, it failed, message read \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr\0xcooooo7b missing files or errors have occurred.
3. Burn new disc and repeat, same again. Then another...!?
4. Download (12.04.2AMD & Intel EM64T) from https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/index.html and burn disc on Lenovo C440 as the optics in the CD/ROm are newer.
5. Failed again.
6. Not happy tried a download onto old laptop using its CD/ROM to burn 12.10 version, again no joy. Throughout the different installations got same message. \ubuntu\wubildr.mbr\0xcooooo7b missing files or errors.

Run out of ideas now, did try switching on and off the CSM legacy in the start up section (this machine requires continued F1 pressing on and of while it starts up), ditto with auto mode, leaving the UEFI on, it took or has priority...?

If any can help, PLEASE a step by step idiot guide, still have my L-Plates on, lol :)

Comment: Windows Eight? Wubi is not supported anymore.

Comment: I'd avoid Wubi because it is an install on top of Windows' NTFS partition and that makes it a lot slower (and prone to not working when Microsoft does things… like Windows 8). It has recently been dropped from the main support lineup so yeah, I'd strongly favour a proper install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable UEFI. The manual for the C440 suggest you can set the "boot mode" from "UEFI" to "Legacy support".

That should let you do a traditional boot-to-CD and that should then let you scrub W8 completely and install Ubuntu on the disk proper.

Answer (score 0):

For a solution that recommends disabling Secure Boot look [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/221835/102029) 
The same guide could be followed with leaving Secure Boot enabled which is the point of using a signed key .iso >=12.04.2 64bit for which UEFI will need to be left enabled also which is applicable to a stand alone install or dual boot install (not using WUBI)
Due to what appears to be misinformation and bad practise it appears there is no idiot proof guide regarding UEFI or Secure Boot. Yet :)
This is mostly due to the complexity of different manufacturers deploying different methods to utilise U/EFI specification and because of this there is similar but different terminology being applied which is adding a lot of confusion. The lack of appropriate information from manufacturers (some but not all) regarding the use of features on their hardware falls well short of acceptable customer service.

Comment: Problem Solved. Thank you all for your help. I had to disable the Quick Start, the UEFI and set the CSM or Legacy to priority, by doing this it disabled the Secure Login. The system had a tizzy as it couldn't find any software, had to manually power off, insert 12.04.2 disc and after a few manual reboots, Ubuntu won the day. Cheers :)